# Как обновляются сертификаты ssl без интернета?

Tags: ssl, https

В браузере есть предустановленные сертификаты ssl, и когда мы впервые открываем браузер на новом компьютере и подключаемся на какой то сайт по https у нас создается цепочка из сертифицированных центров которые предустановленны у нас, до того сайта куда мы коннектимся. Если я все правильно понял.
Но ведь сертификаты периодически обновляются и выдаются только на определенные срок, как будет работать соединение если допустим мы купили компьютер и 5 лет им не пользовались. Там же будут уже устаревшие сертификаты?

Comment: Да, устаревшие. Многие старые устройства уже испытывают проблемы с открытием современных сайтов из-за этого

Comment: Никак не обновляются. И, кстати, не все браузеры носят сертификаты с собой. Они могут использовать и системные сертификаты, которые обновляются при обновлениях системы.

Comment: т.е. чисто теоретически если у меня комп простоял 5 лет без интернета он не будет иметь шансов безопасно подключится к какому либо сайту? и придется как минимум один раз скачать новые обновления по http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос: никак не обновляются.

Поэтому

> если у меня комп простоял 5 лет без интернета он не будет иметь шансов безопасно подключится к какому либо сайту?

ответ таков: как повезёт.

У многих удостоверяющих центров сертификаты действительны ещё много лет. Если компьютером не пользовались пять лет, то с большой долей вероятности все популярные сайты работать будут. Но если он постоит ещё 10 лет, то после 2030 года начнутся проблемы.

[image: Срок действия сертификатов в Ubuntu 18]

*Срок действия сертификатов в Ubuntu 18*

Я написал выше "все популярные сайты работать будут"? Нагло соврал. Сайты с корневым сертификатом "DST Root CA X3" перестанут работать 30 сентября этого года. Истечёт срок действия сертификата. В том числе сайты StackOverflow :)))